# Offering choices that depend on other fields in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new about programming so my code could seems dumb sometimes.

I'm stuck on this problem since 2 days and I looked for on the web but didn't find what I wanted.
I saw related questions on stackoverflow but it seems it?s only for forms and I would like to implement that in the Admin interface.

I would like to display choices in a dropdown menu depending on the choices the user make in an other dropdown menu.

Here my model:

```
    class Airport(BaseModel):
    airport_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Airport Code (ICAO)")
    airport_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Airport Name")
    country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', verbose_name='Country')
    state = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Region', verbose_name='Region')
    city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', verbose_name='City')
    pass

# Afficher dans la partie Admin la valeur au lieu des objets
def __str__(self):
    return 'Airport: {}'.format(self.value)
```

All that, in the Admin :)

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a different data structure:

```
{"USA": ["Alabama", "Alaska"], "Canada": ["Ontario", "Quebec"]}
```

Then in models.py you can load/store the dict in this way:

```
class Airport(BaseModel):
    airport_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Airport Code (ICAO)")
    airport_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Airport Name")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="City")
    country = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

def setlist(self, x):
    self.country = json.dumps(x)

@property
def getlist(self):
    if self.country:
        return json.loads(self.country)
    else:
        return {}
```

In view.py:

```
@login_required
def show_airport(request):
    airport = Airport.objects.first()

    return render(
        request,
        'your_template.html',
        {'airport': airport}
    )
```

So in template will be easier to iterate over keys and values to generate related menus:

```
 {% for key, value in airport.getlist.items %}
    <p>{{key}}: {{value}} </p>
 {% endfor %}
```

Then you can manage user choices client side with javascript with something like:

```
                <form>
                    <select id="nation">
                        {% for key, value in airport.getlist.items %}
                        <option value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                        <select id="states">
                        </select>
               </form>
<script>
      country_list = {{ airport.getlist.items|safe }};
      jQuery.each(country_list[$('#nation').val()], function() {
            $("#states").append('<option value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>')
        });
     $('#nation').on('change', function(event){
        $('#states').empty()
        jQuery.each(country_list[$('#nation').val()], function() {
            $("#states").append('<option value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>')
        });
                });
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Country example using django-autocomplete-light module inside django admin:

```
pip install django-autocomplete-light
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from countryTest.views import CountryAutocompleteFromList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test-country/$', CountryAutocompleteFromList.as_view(), name="country-list-autocomplete")
]
```

views.py

```
from dal.autocomplete import Select2ListView


class CountryAutocompleteFromList(Select2ListView):
    def get_list(self):
        continent = self.forwarded.get('continent', None)

        qs = {
            'Usa': ['California', 'Kansas'],
            'Canada': ['Quebec', 'Ontario']}

        if continent:
            return qs[continent]
```

admin.py

```
from countryTest.models import Country
from django.contrib import admin
from countryTest.forms import CountryForm


class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CountryForm
    model = Country


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Country(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " ".join((str(self.continent), str(self.state)))
```

forms.py

```
from dal import autocomplete

from django import forms


CONTINENT_CHOICES = (('Usa', 'Usa'), ('Canada', 'Canada'))


def get_choices_list():
    return ['Quebec', 'Ontario', 'Kansas', 'California']


class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONTINENT_CHOICES)
    state = autocomplete.Select2ListChoiceField(
        choice_list=get_choices_list,
        widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='country-list-autocomplete', forward=['continent'])
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Andrea ! But, your solution is not for the Admin interface. If I understand well, you're implement that in the view.py so the users can see it. But, I want that in the administration part of Django. Let me know if I had well understand... if not don't hesitate to correct me :) Also what the '@property' and '@login_required' means in your code ? Thanks,

Comment: You can use a Python @property to add a getter/setter to the field and run your custom code there, it's a way to add additional logic inside models. The login_required decorator imported from django.contrib.auth.decorators is used to allow only user logged to access the view. I show you a way to populate select/option field, managing data structure from models to template. Sorry I misunderstood the admin interface part. So you want to manage the data structure inside admin interface, I hope soon to post a solution for your problem.

Comment: I found a module that can solve your problem https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light , There is no more a live demo but a video tutorial is included (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJIHiqWKUXI&feature=youtu.be). I hope it can be helpful, good luck

Comment: Oh yeah ! This package is very usefull, thanks. The video (exactly at 5min35) show what I want. But when I go in the documentation (not the one in youtube footer, it's out of date) but this one : http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#passing-options-to-select2            I can see that he use a lots of form (again) and there is a little part for the admin but I dont understand how to implement it in my code.

Comment: I help you with a full example, I update soon my answer.

Comment: You are welcome Timothee! I update models and forms in my answer to make object creation works in the right way. I hope everything is ok now..if example is useful to you please accept the answer. Best Regards!

Comment: Hi ! I'm back. Sorry but I dont get it. Why do I need to add code in urls.py, view.py and form.py ? Because I just need to implement something in the admin view, so I was gessing that I just need to work in admin.py and models.py (settings.py also). I edit my models in my question to reflect the fact that I'm using a country/states/city generator package. Thansk and sorry to be a little noob on all that...

Comment: I just implement the basic steps necessary according to autocomplete-light documentation. I show you a simple way to solve your problem but I know it's not the only one. I don't think you can extend admin form only working on admin.py and models.py but if you find a way let us know about it. Good luck for your project

Comment: Yep, of course I will post it if I find a way to do it. In the meantimes I will accept your answer ;) Thanks Andrea.

Comment: Thank you very much Timothee! Your generator package seems to be django-cities, I think it can coexist with autocomplete module. Django-cities can be used to populate database while autocomplete manage data selection on UI. I have no experience with this modules but if you need more help feel free to ask. Happy coding!